# Using Spring kafka 1.1.2 with Spring framework 3.1.1

Tags: spring-integration, spring-kafka

I am fairly new to spring integration and spring kafka.
I am having to write a producer for kakfa and am planning to using spring kafka 1.1.2 (as i have used it earlier) and the parent project is using spring framework 3.1.1
I am wanting to understand how do i write the xml configuration for spring kafka 1.1.2 as i could not find anything in the documentation.

Also, I read a little about spring integration kafka module and am not too sure if that's the one i should use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use Spring Kafka with Spring 3.x. It is tested with 4.3.x and will probably work with earlier 4.x releases.

Spring Integration Kafka is an extension to Spring Integration which (since 2.0) sits on top of spring-kafka.

Comment: I think i will have to use the apache kafka producer api to achieve this requirement then..